# Rectifying Java recursive code for Backtracking Graph Coloring Algorithm

Tags: java, recursion, graph, backtracking

The problem is to use Recursion to color a given graph with minimum number of colors such that no adjacent vertices can have the same color.The function signature is static String exhaustive(int color, String prefix) where color is the number of colors being used in that iteration and prefix is string consisting of the color for each node (Example if there are 3 nodes, where node 0 is colored with color 0,node 1 is colored with color 1, node 2 is colored with color 2; then the prefix will be 012). The function returns the string prefix when all nodes are colored. The first call is made with parameters (0,"") meaning trying to color the with 0 colors.
Here is the code I have written. It is working fine and returning correct answer for less than 34 nodes, but for greater than 34, the function is not returning to the main. Any ideas for improving the code would be appreciated. Please let me know if any more information is required.

```
int n=36;
static int[] lastcolor = new int[n];    
static StringBuilder newprefix ;
String addprefix="";
static int node=0,j=0;
Graph.generateFixedSet(n);
verticies2 =Graph.getVerticies();

public static String exhaustive(int color,String prefix)

 {

    newprefix = new StringBuilder(prefix);

        if(prefix.length()==verticies2.size())
            return prefix;
        else
        {
             for(;j<=color;j++)
            {
                lastcolor[node]=j;

                addprefix = Integer.toString(j);
            canColor =1;
            tempnode = (verticies2.get(node)).getEdges();
                for( h=0;h<tempnode.size();h++)
                {
                     if((tempnode.get(h)).getColor() == j)
                {
                    canColor =0;
                    break;
                }

             }

            if(canColor==1)
                {
                        verticies2.get(node).setColor(j);              
                    node++;
                        j=0;
                newprefix.append(addprefix);
                        break;

                }//end if canColor  
            }//end for

        if(j!= 0)
            {


                if(node==1)
                {                           
                        color++;
                        j=0;
                        node=1;
                newprefix.delete(0,newprefix.length());
                newprefix.append("0");

                }//end if node <=1
                else
                {
                        verticies2.get(node).setColor(-1);
                        node--;
                        j=lastcolor[node]+1;
                        newprefix.setLength(node);
                    }
            }//end if j!=0
            prefix = newprefix.toString();
            return exhaustive(color,prefix);
            }//end else
     }//end exhaustive
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Hi @OliCharlesworth ! You re right, but the program is not showing any errors. And since the program is recursive, making thousands of calls to itself, I am not sure how to track the problem . Please advise.

Comment: @HighBit: If the program never returns to main, that means it's stuck in some infinite loop/recursion.  So you should be able to just run the app in the debugger, and then hit Ctrl-C (stop) after a few seconds, and the debugger will show you where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks,I will get back to you with more details about this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recursion. Use a loop... and arraylists if necessary.

Comment: I dont like recursion either, its just that using recursion is a requirement here, as I stated in the first line. Moreover, I think backtracking is best implemented using recursion. Or is there a better way ?

Comment: Wasn't exactly made clear that you had to. I'm curious as to why you're required to use recursion. You can use recursion in a small part of the code right? That'll satisfy the requirement?

Comment: This an Analysis of Algorithms problem and the objective is to demonstrate the exponential complexity of NP complete problems

Comment: Didn't understand much of that... I only have a limited understanding of NP complete... What I can tell you is, using recursion in the form you have is a bad idea. With what you've got already, you could very easily make a loop and lose next to no performance, while eliminating any possibility of stack overflow in the process. Otherwise, I can't think of a good solution using recursion.